# What do first letters like F, V, P in autocomplete mean in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, code-hinting

I understand that V is for variable, folder icon is folder, C is for class, but how about p, m? f is function? Where can I check all those meanings?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P stands for either Parameter or Property (depends on the background colour), M stands for Method and F is Field. You can see the meaning of all icons in this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/symbols.html